# Set InputMode in C++ for Multiplayer Game with EOS

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I hope you're doing well. I have the following code snippet in C++ to switch the UI mode to GameOnly:

```cpp
APlayerController* PlayerController = GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController();
if(PlayerController)
{
    PlayerController->SetInputMode(FInputModeGameOnly());
    PlayerController->bShowMouseCursor = false;
}
```

However, I have a multiplayer game with EOS and therefore don't want to get the FirstPlayerController, but rather the PlayerController of the player currently executing this code. What do I need to change in the code? Thank you for any help

Comment: If this game is online (and I assume it is based on you mentioning EOS): Why _don't_ you want the first player controller? The input mode of the player is set on the client, not on the server. In fact, it sets values in ULocalPlayer and not the player controller itself.